# How to communicate between watchOS and iOS, where both targets are built in different projects

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, watchos

I know how to communication between watchOs and iOS, where both targets are in the same project. But if watchOS is a project and iOS is another one, how to communicate between them?. Maybe we can use app identifier?

Comment: App groups is the most straightforward way. If you can’t put them in a group you have to look into a remote option.

Comment: so you mean that I have to call server API in order to get data?

Comment: If you can’t put them in an app group yes it would have to be remote.